# How to make leadingIcon in OutlinedTextField align to the top of the outline in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

OutlinedTextfield is great as it provides a preformatted textfield that looks graet and that you can twek to your needs. One of the features is a leading Icon the issue is that it will always center vertically (see bottom of picture) and I really want it in the top corner of the outline along with the hint
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can directly change the gravity of leading Icon. Need to do some workaround. Try this,

```
var input by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(
            width = if (isFocused) 2.dp else 1.dp,
            color = if (isFocused) Color.Gray else Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
        )
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
        .height(120.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
 ) {
    Box(
       modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(48.dp, 48.dp),
       contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
       Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Info,
            contentDescription = null
       )
    }
    BasicTextField(
         value = input,
         onValueChange = { input = it },
         modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .onFocusChanged { state ->
                isFocused = state.isFocused
            }
            .padding(top = 8.dp)
    )
 }
```

[image]

You can add more customization to BasicTextField.

Comment: Thanks for this but I would really like to avoid having to redraw a outlinedtextfield from scratch. While achievieng the desired look your code would mean that I would lose all other features from outlinedtextfield and before I do that I prefer to just live with the fact that my textfields look a bit weird

Comment: Fwiw, the prefix/suffix parameters in OutlineTextField place the elements at the top; whereas leading/trailing icons are centered. You can technically place an icon in prefix and have the behavior youre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late but I figured out a solution. Add this to the modifier of your TextArea...

```
.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
```

Next, the leading icon is a @Composable so wrap your icon in a box like this...

```
Box( contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight() 
        .padding(top = 16.dp ) 
   ) {
      Icon( imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(iconRes))
     }
```

The .fillMaxHeight makes the Box take the height of the TextArea and the padding pushes the Icon down to where you'd like it. I got the inspiration from [this article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements).